# SELECT next row of a group as column?

Tags: mysql

I have a many-to-many relation table for 2 tables with this value:

```
docs_detail       deps       docs
+-------+------+  +--+----+  +--+
|docs_id|dep_id|  |id|name|  |id|
+-------+------+  +--+----+  +--+
|   1   |   5  |  | 5|dumA|  | 1|
|   1   |  12  |  |11|dumQ|  | 2|
|   2   |   5  |  |12|dumR|  | 3|
|   2   |  11  |  |13|dumS|  +--+
|   2   |  13  |  +--+----+
|   3   |   5  |
|   3   |  13  |
+-------+------+
```

I want the output for my SELECT query to be something like:

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|docs_id|dep_id|dep_id2|dep_id3|dep_name1|dep_name2|dep_name3|
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1   |   5  |   12  |       |   dumA  |   dumR  |         |
|   2   |   5  |   11  |   13  |   dumA  |   dumQ  |   dumS  |
|   3   |   5  |   13  |       |   dumA  |   dumS  |         |
+-------+------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I've tried this query as a solution

```
SELECT d.*, group_concat(DISTINCT m.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM docs d JOIN docs_detail dd ON d.id = dd.docs_id
JOIN deps m ON dd.dep_id = m.id
GROUP BY dd.docs_id
```

However, using group_concat does not return the next row of dep_id as a column

Are there any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what is the next row of dep_id as a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try query below:

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(depid,',',1) ElSE '' END as dep_id1,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depid,',',2),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_id2,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depid,',',3),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_id3,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(depname,',',1) ElSE '' END as dep_name1,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depname,',',2),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_name2,
       CASE WHEN cnt >= 3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depname,',',3),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_name3
FROM
(SELECT   d.id, group_concat(dd.dep_id ORDER BY dd.dep_id) depid, group_concat(m.name ORDER BY dd.dep_id) depname, count(*) cnt
FROM     docs d 
JOIN     docs_detail dd ON d.id = dd.docs_id
JOIN     deps m ON dd.dep_id = m.id
GROUP BY dd.docs_id) A;
```

From your original query:

1. The first change I made was to use `GROUP_CONCAT` operation differently with two columns. Inside both of the `GROUP_CONCAT` I use identical `ORDER BY` clause to make sure both will have the same ordering results.
2. I've added a `COUNT(*)` operation to be used in the next operation after I turn the main query into a sub-query.
3. In the outer query, I use `CASE` operation to lookup the count result then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the value when the condition matches.

You can refer fiddle demo here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDcVUdfeQbFaWf1X4qdD3j/0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are there any other way to accomodate next columns of dep_idn? Just in case I query: `INSERT INTO deps VALUES(14, dumX)` and `INSERT INTO docs_detail VALUES(2, 5, 14)`

Comment: You can add another operation in the outer query select like `CASE WHEN cnt >= 4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depid,',',4),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_idn` after the `dep_id3` and `CASE WHEN cnt >= 4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(depname,',',4),',',-1) ElSE '' END as dep_namen`  after the `dep_name3`. You only need to take care of the `cnt >= xx` value and the position value in the inner `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. Refer demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDcVUdfeQbFaWf1X4qdD3j/1

Comment: This helps for now. I was hoping that it could add more columns automatically if I query more `INSERT INTO docs_detail VALUES(2, 5, n)`. Please let me know if you have another suggestion :)

Comment: Oh you meant to have just one query and the columns are dynamic according to newly inserted data. I don't think that's achievable with you current data structure unless, if you have a cut-off (maximum) occurrence for each of the `docs_id`; say like each `docs_id` can only occur ten times in both of the `docs_detail` and `deps` tables, you can construct the query once with each `cnt >=1` to `cnt >= 10`. Otherwise, your only option is to use the sub-query but with only two `GROUP_CONCAT` columns data.

Comment: Anyway, it's an interesting concept and I would also like to know if there's a way to achieve that. I'll do some research and see if I can come up with something ;)